# os-prober doesn't find Arch Linux until I manually mount Arch Linux partition

Tags: 12.04, grub2, mount, os-prober

Title says everything. Here is output of Boot info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1169338/

sudo os-prober returns only Windows partition:

```
sudo os-prober
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
```

If I manually mount Arch Linux partition with Nautilus, sudo os-prober returns Windows and also Arch Linux partition:

```
sudo os-prober 
/dev/sda2:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda6::Arch:linux
```

If os-prober don't find Arch Linux partition, Arch Linux don't show on the Grub2, so everytime kernel in Ubuntu is updated I have to manually mount Arch Linux partition and run `sudo update-grub`. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

P.S.: I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: @belacqua no, at least not in 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a workaround than a real solution, but if you add your arch partition to `/etc/fstab`, it will always be mounted, so the updates won't mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Detecting_other_operating_systems) you have to mount the partition first which contains the other systems, than you should remake your grub.cfg. 
On Ubuntu it should be `grub-install` and on Arch it should be `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.